# How to connect on-prem server to Google Cloud SQL over private IP, where private IP conflicts with local subnet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to connect my Cloud SQL to my on-prem MySQL server, via private IP. I have a Dedicated Interconnect established between on-prem and the Shared VPC that "hosts" the Cloud SQL.

However, the private IP of my Cloud SQL overlaps with one of the local subnets used in my on-prem environment.

Is there any way that I can configure this connection? Given the conflicting IP, the server on-premise will never find the Cloud SQL as it stands. I don't feel like Cloud SQL auth proxy/IAP solves my issue, I think that only allows users to connect, as opposed to systems like a DB server.

Comment: Check this out https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/resolving-overlapping-ip-issue-when-connecting-tofrom-bayu-wibowo/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with Cloud interconnect, the IP address space on your on-premises network and on your VPC network [must not overlap](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/concepts/overview#:%7E:text=The%20IP%20address%20space%20on%20your%20on%2Dpremises%20network%20and%20on%20your%20VPC%20network%20must%20not%20overlap%2C%20or%20traffic%20is%20not%20routed%20properly.), or traffic is not routed properly.

[Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) cannot be used, as it only applies to external destinations - ie if you wanted to reach the on-prem via external ip through the internet and not via private ip over interconnect.

You may want to consider a third party solution called Aviatrix Mapped NAT that does NAT mapping to virtual subnets to solve the overlapping address issue. Kindly check this [document](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/resolving-overlapping-ip-issue-when-connecting-tofrom-bayu-wibowo) on how to set it up. Again, this is not a Google Cloud Platform feature and may or may not work with your setup.

[image]

Comment: Aviatrix is a good product that works well with Google Cloud.